# Blender 2.79b model export to Collada

Tags: export, collada

I am trying to export from Blender to Collada .dae and seems that textures are not exported

Here it is a video with the steps

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ELOeZovAhHoxm92P1poLjDk5EUdXZ8l/view?usp=sharing

What am I missing?

Comment: try to uncheck the "Only Selected UV map" checkbox

Comment: tried, same result -> no texture exported, only the mesh

Comment: here it is blender project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JESub-RWzdYmicfQB6IMWnuy6P4Iksli/view?usp=sharing

Comment: really weird. Copying of textures seems to only work if the image is selected under the in the uv editor when blender renderer is selected (even if switching back to cycles afterwards).

Comment: I'll try to make a small writeup as an answer after work if no-else already did it by then but for me setting the textures in the blender render worked. Both setting it as a [uv texture](https://youtu.be/-_RdpCOjwVc) and setting it as a [material texture](https://youtu.be/iU6anj9Y2r4) but not as a pure node texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Blender Exporter does not seem to be able to embed textures into Collada *.dae files (as of 2.79b).

It can however save textures alongside Collada files. To do that it has two sources of texture files.

### Materials as texture source

See [this video](https://youtu.be/iU6anj9Y2r4) if you want to see it in action.

This is used when you select `Materials` in the `Texture Options` section of the Collada Export dialog.

[image: Exporter Texture Options, Materials selected]

The steps you need to make sure the texure is set, do the following:

1. Be sure that you are in **`Blender Render`** or **`Blender Game`** mode (you can switch back to another renderer after you set the texture)
   1a. Select your object and go into the textures tab of the Properties Panel
2. make sure that you are editing the textures of the material
3. add at least one texture of type Image (you can add multiple textures and all will get saved)
4. set the image for the texture

[image: Steps to set Material Texture]

### UV Texture as texture source

See [this video](https://youtu.be/-_RdpCOjwVc) if you want to see it in action.

This is used when you select `UV Textures` in the `Texture Options` section of the Collada Export dialog.

[image: Exporter Texture Options, UV Texture selected]

The steps you need to make sure the texure is set, do the following:

1. Be sure that you are in **`Blender Render`** or **`Blender Game`** mode (you can switch back to another renderer after you set the texture)
2. Select your object and go into edit mode
3. open a `UV/Image Editor` panel and set the image you want to export as the texuture (you can switch back into object mode and this image will persist as the one that will be exported).

[image: Steps to set UV Texture]